# How to extract video and audio track from multi-track wmv video

Tags: audio, video, vlc-media-player

I have a number of WMV files with two video tracks and one audio track. How do I extract the second video track and the audio track so I can get rid of the useless first video track?
I try playing these on VLC and select the second video track but the player always freezes if I try to fast forward. I would also be happy with a video player that would allow me to play the second video track and wouldn't freeze if skipping ahead. I am on a mac mini using OS 11.6.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-map` switch on ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0 -map -0:v:0 -c copy output.mp4
```

Where `input.mp4` is your media with 2 video streams and output is the new media with only the second video stream + audio.